# CSS Styling In A 12 Column Grid

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

Hey guys, I need a little help on the [site](http://goo.gl/EmO0o) I'm working on . I'm trying to move the two images so they are side by side to the right of the navigation menu, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6rgu.jpg). I've tried using floats on the divs responsible for the pictures and the list where the menu resides, but to no avail. Im using a 12 column in 960 grid system. This (http://pastebin.com/nfrctRhS) is the CSS code for the page. I really appreciate any help you guys can offer, as I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it working already? as in my browser it seems to be aligned side by side. But there is lot of mis-alignment in terms of upper <header> tag and the  div#main. I would recomment not to use header tag(HTML5) as it is not supported by all browsers. Use a centering wrapper to contain all elements of body. That will fix the alignment of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you take off your images of the div #featured and add

```
#featured {
    width:100px;
    float:left;  
}
```

?

Comment: What do you mean by "take off your images of the div #featured"? Like move the images out of that div and into the parent <nav>?

Comment: oops sorry for my bad english. Yes move images after like <div id="featured"></div> <img blabla /> <img blabla /> and add the css that i wrote

Comment: Okay, I did what you said and deployed it on the site. As you can see (http://goo.gl/EmO0o), nothing really changed except the width of the menu. For some reason, it looks like the float has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is nav has a padding-right:800px; This means there is not room within the nav div for them to fit.

set

```
header nav { padding-right:0px; }
```

for the desired result.